# Mapstructure isn't decoding json keys starting with @

Tags: go

I am trying to parse data, where some of the json keys start with @. This is a simplified version of the data I am dealing with. The mapstructure doesn't decode the Id1 field.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/mitchellh/mapstructure"
)

type test struct {
    Id1 string `json:"@id1"`
    Id2 string `json:"id2"`
}

func main() {
    input := map[string]interface{}{
        "@id1": "foo",
        "id2":  "bar"}

    var result test
    err := mapstructure.Decode(input, &result)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%#v", result)
}
Output: main.test{Id1:"", Id2:"bar"}
```

This however works fine with the standard json library:
https://play.golang.org/p/P-6odZ4yrYU

Comment: `mapstructure` doesn't decode JSON keys at all, nor does it use the `json` tag. As the name implies, it converts between `map`s and `struct`s.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use mapstructure tag instead of json:

```
type test struct {
    Id1 string `mapstructure:"@id1"`
    Id2 string `mapstructure:"id2"`
}
```